# Doctrine not generating entity ID

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to create an entity, but i get a null value on the id of the entity, which is a generated value.

Controller :

```
if($buRepository->findOneBy(['buName' => $row['Bu1'], 'dateDeleted' => null]) > null)

elseif($buRepository->findOneBy(['buName' => $row['Bu1'], 'dateDeleted' => null]) === null) 
{
       $bu1 = new Bu();
       $bu1->setBuName($row['Bu1']);
       $bu1->setLastUpdated(new \DateTime('now'));
       $bu1->setDateDeleted(null);
       $bu1->setSrcId(3);
       $bu1->setIdInSource($bu1->getBuId());
}
```

Entity :

```
 /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="bu_id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $buId;
```

Once my entity tries to flush i get an error on the buid, saying it can't be null.

Comment: Are you persisting `$entityManager->persist($bu1)` someplace? What type of database (mysql, postgres etc) are you trying to persist to since the identity strategy is not implemented for all types of databases.  Do any of your entities work?  Consider using `bin/console make:entity` to make a test entity just to get a working example.

Comment: yeah the entity gets persisted, its the last tine of the code before exiting the the if or elseif stement. mysql (mariadb)

Comment: Okay. So what is this line: `$bu1->setIdInSource($bu1->getBuId());` supposed to be doing?  It sort of looks like you are trying to get the id and use for something before the flush?  The id does not get set until the entity is flushed to the database.  If you do need to use an id before flushing then you need to use a NONE strategy and basically generate it yourself.  Typically using a GUID.

Comment: I'm guessing you are trying to establish an association between your Bu and Src entities?  If so then you are going about it the wrong way.  Doctrine manages that sort of thing for you.  You very seldom use the actual id values directly.  Take a look at the docs on associations and maybe follow a couple of the examples until you get comfortable with them.  It's a key part of Doctrine.

Comment: @Cerad i'm not creating an association, Idinsource is a string, so im just getting the Id of bu and seting in idinsourcem, there is no relations

Comment: Okay so you are passing a null to something that expects a string.  Hence the error.  Remember that using IDENTITY means that the database itself is generating the actual id value.  So it will simply not be set until you persist and flush the Bu entity.  Once again, if you want the id before flushing then you need to generate it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Buid` isn't created and assign if the entity isn't flushed, the best way to go around it, is to put a trigger in place.
Since `IdInSource` can't be of `NULL` value but is suppose to be the `BuId` (no relation just assigning the `INT` value), i assigned it a value of 0.
For each entity with a `IdInSource` of `0` my database trigger replaces it with the `BuId`.

Answer (score -3):

Try AUTO strategy which fall to AUTO_INCREMENT for MySQL

Comment: Given that [AUTO defaults to IDENTITY for MySql](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifier-generation-strategies), it is doubtful that your `suggestion` will have a successful outcome.

Comment: @Cerad is right, changing the strategy isnt going to change anything